# RedisTemplate leads to unsafe deserialization in Fortify's dynamic code evaluation

Tags: java, deserialization, fortify, spring-data-redis

In making spring redis data template, I use:

```
RedisTemplate<String, xxxDTO> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
```

Then I also set the deserializer to a custom one that white lists certain class in case of unsafe deserialization.

Fortify somehow still highlights:

```
new RedisTemplate<>();
```

as unsafe deserialization during the dynamic code evaluation, within the kingdom Input Validation and Representation.

How to make a RedisTemplate without being flagged?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and the Fortify scan report flagged this as 'Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization'. Adding the solution since I didn't get a proper solution on *StackOverflow*.

**Initial Code**

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
    RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();

    RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    return template;
}
```

The problem was happening due to this line `RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();`

Now, using safe serializers are recommended and I have used `Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` for serializing and deserializing objects. I was already using `StringRedisSerializer` for strings.

Additionally, I initialized RedisTemplate<String, Object>, thereby specifying the key and value types.

**Solution**

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> objectSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);

    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(objectSerializer);

    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.setHashValueSerializer(objectSerializer);

    template.setEnableDefaultSerializer(true);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    return template;
}
```

This resolved my Fortify issue.

Answer (score -2):

I found my own answer through trial and experiment with the static code analyzer. 
Apparently you should re-write the implementation of RedisTemplate class and do your own implementation of jdkserializationredisserializer.

Specifically, you should override and make a deserializing converter which will be invoked in jdkserializationredisserializer class in constructor method, since it doesn't use any validation by default(it's using DeserializingConverter). Then in your deserializing converter, you implement the white-list approach that specifies what classes are expected. Make sure you unit test them too because they might have dependent classes needed to be deserialized.

Comment: Hi, could you share maybe a code snipped of how you managed to re-write the implementation of RedisTemplate?

Comment: If you found a solution, you should share the same.